# Find distance of opposing peaks in hypercube

Tags: graph-theory

*First of all, I am sorry for my english, it is very bad and I realize that.*

We have a hypercube of ***k*** order ( k=3 in this case http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~demmel/cs267-1995/lecture10/HypercubeMesh.gif).

---

**Opposite peaks** are 2 vertexes whose every coordinate is different ( 
[0,0] => [1,1] are opposite peaks, [1,0,1] => [0,1,0] are opposite peaks, [1,0,0,0] => [0,1,1,1] are opposite peaks, [1,1,1] => [0,0,1] are not opposite peaks)
***What is the distance of opposing peaks in hypercube of k order?***

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#n_dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  compute the square of the distance, which is the sum of the squares of the difference of the components.  There are $k$ components, and the square of the difference is ??????

Comment: Is the answer k?

Comment: That is the square of the distance, yes

Comment: Wow. So is that it? Was it that easy? Thank you!!!!